# Specifying variable range in Verilog using for loop

Tags: hardware, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to write this code:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= CONST - 1'b1; i = i + 1'b1)
                    begin : loop_inst

                        if (i < 3)
                        begin
                            if (changed[i] & !done_q[i])
                            begin
                                writedata[3-i] = en[i];
                                writedata[2-i:0] = readdata[2-i:0];
                                writedata[15:4-i] = readdata[15:4-i];
                            end
                        end
                        else
                        ...
```

Basically, the location of the bit I am trying to write to (`en`) changes depending on which address I am talking to, depending on `i`. This code is not synthesizable because `i` is not a constant.

Is there any other workaround to this? The only workaround I know is writing out those three statements CONST times. I am hoping I DON'T have to do that in the end. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Which tool is this? Can you post the minimum code that compiles with the error?

Comment: The tool is Quartus. The error is: Error (10734): Verilog HDL error at top.v(733): i is not a constant.

I heavily edited my code when i posted it here. That's all I can post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to copy `readdata` to `writedata` all the time, but fill in the LSBs with `en` if certain special case conditions are met. I'm also going to assume that the `for` loop you have is in an `always` block, and that you're intending to build combo logic.

The `for` loop as you've it written doesn't make much sense to me from a hardware perspective. A `for` loop is used for building arrays of logic, and as you've 
written it you'll have at least 3 logic cones trying to set values on the entire `writedata` bus. (If it generates anything at all, it'll be some weird priority structure).

That said, it's probably the range selects that your compiler is complaining about, ie the `writedata[2-i:0]` rather than the `writedata[3-i] = en[i];` (anything with `:` in the part select). If you want to do something along those lines, you can use 'indexed part selects' ( `+:` or `-:`) but there are better solutions in this case.

I'd rewrite it as follows - assuming I've assumed correctly :)

```
always @( /*whatever*/ ) begin

    // default assignment
    writedata = readdata;

    // overwrite some bits in writedata for special cases
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) begin
        if( changed[i] & !done_q[i] )
             writedata[3-i] = en[i];
    end
end
```

In this code, I'm setting `writedata` to `readdata`, and then tweaking the resulting value of `writedata` if the special cases are in play. The `for` loop is building 3 logic cones, one for each of the bits in `writedata[3:1]`. I'd double-check if the bit mapping is what you intend -ie, mapping `en[2:0]` on to `writedata[1:3]`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I am such an idiot for not thinking of this... of course this is the obvious solution! I just double checked, and the Quartus compiler was only giving an error on the ranged assignments, not the one with [3-i].

And you did assume everything correctly :)